Keycloak user session message customization
I am trying to access the update user account mail from keycloak. But i am already logged in as another user in the keycloak. So, a session message is generated as below,

In this message i have to replace username with the email address,
You are already authenticated as different user 'email' in this session. Please log out first. 

How to use SPI to customize the above message to replace username with email id?
I have seen the place where it is triggered in keycloak Git Link, from the stack overflow question. But how to override this function by using a custom keycloak SPI?
